# How to reflect normals once they have been flipped in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, normals

I am trying to play a 360 video within a sphere. I am not an expert at unity or 3D modeling but I've managed to get the 360 video to invert its normals and play on the inside of the sphere.

The problem is the video has been flipped by the inversion (right is left and left is right). I need to correct this and despite the last three hours of searching I cannot find a solution that I understand. This is the code I've been using as a custom shader to achieve the inversion:

```
Shader "Custom/Flip Normals" {
    Properties {
        _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
    SubShader {

        Tags { "RenderType" = "Opaque" }

        Cull Off

        CGPROGRAM

        #pragma surface surf Lambert vertex:vert
        sampler2D _MainTex;

        struct Input {
            float2 uv_MainTex;
            float4 color : COLOR;
        };

        void vert(inout appdata_full v) {
            v.normal.xyz = v.normal * -1;
        }

        void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
             fixed3 result = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex);
             o.Albedo = result.rgb;
             o.Alpha = 1;
        }

        ENDCG

    }

      Fallback "Diffuse"
}
```

Note: messing with the camera or the video file itself are not ideal options.

Comment: I made a program in DirectX to do the same thing you are describing, just not in Unity and not for videos but It still might help since I use a sphere aswell, here is the program and the source: http://katianie.com/blog/vr/   https://github.com/Katianie/Graphics-Programming/tree/master/DirectX/PanoramicVR

Comment: Try setting the scale of the video to -1. I know in Unreal Engine 4 if you set the scale negative, it turns the object "inside out" so to say.

Comment: setting the X scale to a negative value actually worked. I'm surprised I didn't think of trying that. This sort of seems like a band-aid solution but I'm not one for looking a gift horse in the mouth when it comes to deadlines, Thank you.

Comment: No problem, that's good to know it works the same in Unity as UE4. Yea it is strange, when I first came across it I thought the same thing but its apparently the right way to do it.

Comment: There is now a built in shader solution for unity that allows this, but as a skybox which I guess is not what you wanted. you create a new material as skybox/panoramic and attach your vid to it. https://blogs.unity3d.com/2017/07/27/how-to-integrate-360-video-with-unity/